# multistep module to create multistep registration form

Tags: users, 6, forms

I need to use the [multistep](http://drupal.org/project/multistep) module to create a multistep registration form in Drupal 6.

In the multistep module you can easily create a multistep form for a content type but I need to use it instead of Drupal normal registration page.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience, **[CTools](http://drupal.org/project/ctools)** works great for multistep forms using the CTools form wizard. I've already used it successfully but never tried with user registration.

You can follow a nice tutorial for that case here:
**[Multistep registration form in Drupal 6](http://shvetsgroup.com/blog/multistep-registration-form-drupal%C2%A06)**

Another tutorial:
**[Intro to Drupal 6 Multistep Form Domination Using Chaos Tools](http://www.nicklewis.org/using-chaos-tools-form-wizard-build-multistep-forms-drupal-6)**

Happy coding :)

Comment: I used the very same tutorial and it worked, I also created a module for that, you think we should distribute it back to the community ?

Comment: I think ctools wizard is very straightforward and creating a multi-step registration is a project specific requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Webform](http://drupal.org/project/webform) module. For multisteps you can use a field type 'pagebreak' between the steps. It is very easy. Try this once

> Webform is the module for making surveys in Drupal. After a submission, users may be sent an e-mail "receipt" as well as sending a notification to administrators. Results can be exported into Excel or other spreadsheet applications. Webform also provides some basic statistical review and has and extensive API for expanding its features.

Comment: Just an FYI, it's always useful to put the link to the module into your answer if you're suggesting one.